# How to authenticate an HTTP request to remote server that can be utilize on end user browser?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest, remote-access

Details of the problem:

- There is one page which is actually a streaming to The Axis IP camera which spits MJPEG output
- It requires user to log in with the user name/password promp on browser
- I am using this stream to show video directly on a web page
- It shows video correctly but asks user to provide correct user name and password set for the camera
- I tried to logging in to this camera on server side using HTTP requests and then I realized I authenticated server request not the browser the end user is using.

So what I want is a method server side or client side, that can allow me to log-in to camera automatically when my end-users visit this page.

I am using asp.net with c# 2005

Thanks,

Vipul

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to build a proxy that sits between the user and the camera. For every new connection that comes in from the user, you open a backend connection to the camera and login first before streaming the data out.

Your asp.net page would talk to this proxy.

Comment: That way will consume bandwidth from both ways and speed will also decrease.

Comment: @Vipul you don't have many other options. Without it, the request will be coming form the users browser and so they will have to authenticate.